# How to deal with different subsampling time in economic datasets for deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, economics

I am building a deep learning model for macro-economic prediction. However, different indicators varies widely when it comes to its subsampling time, ranging from minutes to annually.

[Dataframe example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX4xg.png)

The picture contains the 'Treasury Rates (DGS1-20)' which is sampled daily and 'Inflation Rate(CPALT...)' which is sampled monthly. These features are essential for the model to train and dropping out the NaN rows would result in too little data.

I've read some books and articles about how to deal with missing data that includes down sampling to monthly time frames, swapping the NaNs with -1, filling it with averages between the last and next value etc. But the methods that I read mostly deals with data sets that has a missing value of about 10% of the whole dataset while in this case of mine, the monthly sampled 'Inflation(CPI)' is missing at 90+% if I combine it with the 'Treasury Rate' dataset.

I was wondering if there was any workaround to handle missing values, particularly for economic data where the sampling time gap ranges so widely. Thank you